# c++ std::map перебрать все элементы

Tags: c++

Как перебрать все элементы в std::map? У меня такая карта:

```
map<const char *, EGE_Texture> _textures;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
for(auto& item : _textures)
{
    cout << item.first << " : " << item.second << endl; //Вывод ключей и значений
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать так конечно:

```
  for(auto it = _textures.begin(); it != _textures.end(); ++it) {
      cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl; //Вывод ключей и значений
  }
```

Однако проблема то в том что нет никакого смысла в хэш таблице в которой ключом являются двоичные данные текстуры, а значением указатель на неё. Вам точно нужен не map, все это можно положить в обычный класс и сделать вектор из них.

P.S. Хотя может я ошибся и const char* это был путь к файлу текстуры.

Comment: Ключем здесь вообще является указатель.
Надо использовать std::string.

Comment: Эх крестопроблемы, крестопроблемчики...
`char*, unsigned char*, wchar_t*, std::string, std::wstring, LPSTR, LPWSTR, jstring, vector<char> myPath` и 3 способа использования const в объвлении переменной в придачу.

Comment: Вы просто не умеете их готовить :)